# If you’re using react-navigation you need to manually hide the headers / tab bars to take advantage of fullscreen videos?

Tags: react-native, tabs, header, hide

I'm using **[react-native-af-video-player](https://github.com/abbasfreestyle/react-native-af-video-player)**, which requires a full screen.

The article said: If you're using **react-navigation**, you need to manually hide the headers / tab bars to take advantage of full-screen videos.

```
"react-navigation": "1.5.3", "react-native": "0.55.4"
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigationOptions`

So you desired code will be:

```
  // navigation Options
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    tabBarVisible: false
  };
```